# Updating Values for Sub keys in a Nested Dict Overwrites Old Values

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-lab

I'm currently struggling with an issue in my nested dictionaries and I cannot for the life of me diagnose what is going on.

So... I start out with a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
ctrl_data = 
{'Loop1': {'time_stamp': [],
      'pv': [],
      'sp': [],
      'op': [],
      'string_mode': [],
      'auto_mode': [],
      'cascade_mode': [],
      'operational': [],
      'operational_min': [],
      'operational_max': []},
     'Loop2': {'time_stamp': [],
      'pv': [],
      'sp': [],
      'op': [],
      'string_mode': [],
      'auto_mode': [],
      'cascade_mode': [],
      'operational': [],
      'operational_min': [],
      'operational_max': []},
     'Loop3': {time_stamp': [],
    ......etc.
```

What I want to do is use a a nested for loop to iterate through this and update each key in Loop1, then Loop2, then Loop3 and so on.

Each list item should be updated based on a function that pulls in data from a database based on a tag_id which is stored in a data frame that looks like this:

```
               Loop1   Loop2   Loop3.......
id_type                                                     
pv               1       9      17  
sp               2      10      18  
op               3      11      19  
string_mode     NaN     NaN     NaN 
auto_mode        4      12      20  
cascade_mode     5      13      21  
operational      6      14      22  
operational_min  7      15      23  
operational_max  8      16      24
```

The loop I'm using looks like this:

```
indexer = 0
for i in df1.columns: # pulls the column name from the above df
    for j in df1[i].iteritems(): #pulls the tagid from that row in the df
        if i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[0]: # just checks that the loop is iterating correctly
            print(j[1])
            print(i)
            ctrl_data[i]['time_stamp'] = values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[0]
            ctrl_data[i][order[0]].clear()
            print(ctrl_data[i][order[0]])
            ctrl_data[i][order[0]] = values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
            print(ctrl_data[i][order[0]])
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[1]:
            ctrl_data[i][order[1]] = values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[2]:
            ctrl_data[i][order[2]] = values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[3]:
            if j[1] == 'NaN':
                ctrl_data[i][order[3]] = j[1]
            else:
                ctrl_data[i][order[3]] = values_pull_ctrl(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1] 
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[4]:
            if j[1] == 'NaN':
                ctrl_data[i][order[4]] = j[1]
            else:
                ctrl_data[i][order[4]] = values_pull_ctrl(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[5]:
            if j[1] == 'NaN':
                ctrl_data[i][order[5]] = j[1]
            else:
                ctrl_data[i][order[5]] = values_pull_ctrl(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[6]:
            if j[1] == 'NaN':
                ctrl_data[i][order[6]] = j[1]
            else:
                ctrl_data[i][order[6]] = values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[7]:
            ctrl_data[i][order[7]] = j[1]
        elif i == list(ctrl_data.keys())[indexer] and j[0] == order[8]:
            ctrl_data[i][order[8]] = j[1]
        else:
            print('Unable to find data for loop: {}, type: {}, tag_id: {}'.format(i,j[0],j[1]))
            print('')

    indexer = indexer + 1
```

**The loop seems to be running correctly, in terms of it's pulling the correct tagids and column names but for some reason when it pulls the data, evertime it re-enters the first for loop, it overwrites the from the previous for loop. Please see the attached screenshots of this behaviour.**
[image: Data Overwrites previous data for pv each time through the loop]
 [image: Result dict only contains data from last time the sub key was pulled]

Comment: Using *recursion* is better here instead of for loop. Your for loop looks so convoluted it's really hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks Ch3steR. I'm relatively new to programming and have never used that before. What is the advantage of using that over a for loop in this scenario? to me it seems that the for loop is running correctly because it's matching the correct loop name to the correct id.

Comment: @Brain Keith *Recursive* function is a function which calls itself. Your dictionary is arbitrary nested. So, recursive function would have been better.

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR I’ll try that out and see if it works! If it does I’ll post it as a solution.

Comment: If you want I can post a basic recursive answer but you have to edit it according to your requirements. I can post a complete answer but you wouldn't learn anything. And you get to learn only when you try right?

Comment: Hahaha if there's anything that I've learned from programming so far it's that learning only happens through an immense amount of struggling. I've found some examples on line that I think can work but I'll let you know if I can't figure out the solution myself. Thank you @Ch3steR!

Comment: @Ch3steR I was able to find the solution for the overwriting problem by researching the properties of arbitrarily nested dictionaries and I posed the correct format below. That one comment just saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now found the solution. As @Ch3steR noted, my dictionary is arbitrarily nested. I don't fully understand the implications of that, but what I THINK was happening is that it when I wrote:

```
ctrl_data[i][order[0]] = values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]
```

It was overwriting the data for every pv,sp,op, etc. key with the new data. I'm not 100% sure why this was the case since ctrl_data[i] should be calling the main key 'Loop1' but regardless, the solution was found at this site under the section 'Add or Update Nested Dictionary Items':
https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-nested-dictionary/

The solution was to use this format:

```
ctrl_data[i] = {order[0]: values_pull_process(j[1],start1,end1,num_points,token,base_uri)[1]}
```

**NOTE:**
Using .append or other list methods also caused the same original issue.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Try implementing recursive function also.